# ASP.NET Ajax Control Library Best for Mobile Web

Tags: iphone, asp.net, android, ajax, mobile

I need a set of basic Ajax controls that work well with ASP.NET. I need the basic controls, like lists, trees, masked edits, accordians etc. However, my twist is that many of the users of my web app will be using mobile browsers on Android and iPhone, so the controls need to work well in small screen touch oriented formats. (For example, the ASP.Net Ajax library resize control just doesn't work well in this environment.)

Does anyone have any experience and recommendations in this area?

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 frameworks that works well on mobile browsers and are touch friendly:

http://www.sencha.com/
http://www.jqtouch.com/

They both are good. But it would be hard to use them with asp.net because of the nature of asp.net web forms (view states, generated id's, one form that wraps the content and so on).
If you want to use them then you'll need to use different development approach than in standard asp.net web forms application. Your site will be more like a set of json services with only a few pages with simple structure and no server forms. So it seems to me that it will be better to create a separate WCF json service to expose the data and a simple website with one or several start pages without server forms and with code to init and launch the application.